# Can you still play Runescape in an internet browser?

Tags: runescape

I was attempting to play Runescape through a browser, but I got a message saying it would not work with my Mac OS specs (it needs Windows and Internet explorer). After downloading a Windows 10 VM and trying with a browser, I was still unable to get Runescape to be playable in a browser.

How can I play Runescape through a browser, if it is still possible?

Comment: Which browser did you trying in your VM? IE?

Comment: @Wondercricket I thought it was IE, but looking back it may have been Microsoft Edge (Same icons). Would that make a difference?

Comment: Perhaps. I can’t test right now, but Jagexs [support](https://www.runescape.com/browser-support) says it can be played in IE. Doesn’t say anything about Edge, but does confirm Chrome and FireFox won’t run it.

Comment: I am not completely familiar with how the game works in a browser, but I do know that [the Java client is no longer available](https://support.runescape.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360003479697), and I suspect this is related to your issues based on what I'm reading about making sure your browser supports Java (the Java client stopped being supported some time earlier this month iirc)

Comment: Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer are incredibly different. Internet Explorer should still work fine according to the site in February 2020. Edge is based on the same engine as Google Chrome, and bears no relation to IE in its code.

Answer (score 6):

Contrary to the official website and comments in response to the OP, there has been no way to play the current version of RuneScape in the browser for around six months now.

Since 2016, Jagex had been pushing their new native client. Both clients were previously available for download at the same time, but in November of 2019, the links to the Java client were removed and only accessible had you done some digging. A month later, though, in December, the Java-based client was completely discontinued. And, due to protocol changes, previously downloaded versions of the client no longer work either.

With the discontinuation of the JavaScript-based client, the Java applet had been the only remaining version of the game playable in the browser.